# Добавление UserControl в Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал UserControl, которую мне надо добавить на форму. Использовал Controls, но я не знаю как при удалении Controls.Clear() вернуть форму обратно, т.е я даю контроль UserControl но как обратно отдать контроль форме не знаю.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 user = new UserControl1(this);
    user.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.Controls.Add(user);

}
```

Comment: `я не знаю как при удалении Controls.Clear() вернуть форму обратно, т.е я даю контроль UserControl но как обратно отдать контроль форме не знаю.` эта фраза просто не понятна. Можете как то другими словами переписать, более подробно?

Comment: `control = this.Controls;` - ??

Comment: Я добавляю UserControl в форму и даю ей контроль, удаляя при этом контроль с формы
this.Controls.Clear();

Допустим мне уже не нужна UserControl, а форма у которой я отобрал контроль нужна. Как вернуть контроль форме?

Comment: `private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Controls.Clear(); }`

Comment: Какой контроль Вы даёте? У кого Вы какой контроль забираете? Вы просто удалили с формы все элементы, после чего добавили новый. Распишите вопрос адекватно, чтобы каждый мог его понять